# Detect Retina screen in Qt for Maya

Tags: c++, qt, retina-display, maya

I am developing a Qt (version 4.8) plugin for Maya and am creating a 60-pixels-high toolbar to which I add 60-pixels-high icons:

```
actionToolBar = addToolBar(tr("Actions"));
actionToolBar->setIconSize(QSize(60,60));

actionButton = new QToolButton;
actionButton->setIcon(QIcon(createMyPixmap()));
actionToolBar->addWidget(actionButton);
```

On a normal display, the icons appear properly in the bar, but on a retina display, the bar appears half of its size and therefore the icons are truncated, which requires me to have a 120x120 toolbar. How can I detect the retina screen and then dynamically create the right toolbar size ?

Comment: Qt4 has no retina support. You should look some native ways.

Comment: Ok thanks. Like looking pixels vs points ?

Comment: You may get window native handle and detect DPI with platform-specific API.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for QScreen property [devicePixelRatio](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#devicePixelRatio-prop)

As you had pointed out in comments, this was introduced in Qt5

Comment: Thanks, but these only appeared with Qt 5, and I have to use Qt 4.8.